# Prolog-SWI: procedure which removes one occurence

Tags: prolog

I have the next function from the book:

```
% Signature: select (X,HasXs,OneLessXs)/3 
% purpose: The list OneLessXs is the result of removing 
 one occurrence of X from the list HasXs. 
select(X,[X|Xs],Xs).  *rule number 1* 
select(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|Zs]) :- select(X,Ys,Zs).  * rule number 2*

?- select(4,[2,3,2,4,5,2,4],X].
X=[2,3,2,5,2,4]
```

But I didn't understand how it finds the correct answer. After it removes all the Y=!X, It come to a rule number 1, with: `Xs=4,5,2,4`, then it return `true`. and what then? If it continue to rule 2, then he also remove the next "4". If it doesn't continue to rule 1, then How Zs is `[2,3,2,5,2,4]`? I think Im missing a basic rule.

Comment: Just a note, considering swi-prolog has 51 followers and you would be hard pressed to find an answer-er, I added the prolog tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand why this is happening by thinking of how it's going to be executed.
So you have:

```
% I use K here instead of X, so there is no
% confusion with the X on the rules
select(4,[2,3,2,4,5,2,4], K).
```

First, it will check rule 1, but `4 != 2` so it will continue to rule 2. At rule 2, you have these "bindings":

```
X = 2
[Y | Ys] = [2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4] (which means Y = 2, Ys = [3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4])
[Y | Zs] = [2 | Zs] (because Y was binded to 2)
```

And `K` is binded to `[2 | Zs]` and **not** just `Zs`. The next `select` call which will be `select(4, [3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4], Zs)` finds `Zs` and so on. That's why the returned result is:
`K=[2,3,2,5,2,4]` and not `K=[5, 2, 4]` as you was expecting.